# print a float value as degrees in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, computational-geometry, angle

Given a 90 degree angle, print the bisecting angle **in degrees.**

```
import math 

#given angle
abc = 90

#m is midpoint of ac, therefor
abm = abc/2
mbc = abc - abm
degrees = math.degrees(mbc)
print(degrees)
```

but when I print it out, i get 2578.3100780887044

if I don't use math.degrees() then I get:

```
mbc = abc - abm
#degrees = math.degrees(mbc)
print(mbc)
```

45.0

but what I need is:   45°

I found math.radians() and math.degrees() but I feel like there is something I am missing. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 returns a float for every integer or float division. If you want you can floor the result writing: `abm = int(abc/2)`. This will give you mbc as an integer.
On the other hand, `math.degrees()` converts an angle from radians to degrees, giving a float as a result. If you want to floor the result of the conversion you can do `degrees = int(math.degrees(mbc))`.

Comment: well, i suppose the point is that i want the number 45 degrees. i dont want 45 radians converted to degrees. 45 degrees is 0.7853982 radians... but it seems like we are adding extra steps just to force the proble to use radians so that we can print it as degrees. if I know the number already is 45.0 is there a simple way to output 45 degrees instead?

Comment: @Adam You can convert the variable that contains the answer into a string and then concatenate with the degree symbol °. After you've converted abm to an integer like shown in the answer, you can do: `str(mbc) + '°'`. In this way you will have the string "45°"

Comment: thats not quite the same as having a degree representation of the number though, is it?

Comment: @Adam the same goes for `math.degrees()`: it does only the conversion, but it does not represent an actual degree inside python. As you stated, if you print degrees after using  `math.degrees()` it does not add the "°" symbol.

Comment: you were totally right brotha. i was thinking it was a different numerical representation. but couldnt figure out why. i come from java background, and python is a bit weird for me so far.